# CSS- Can't add margin between links?

Tags: css, drupal, menu, hyperlink

I'm using a CMS . I have a menu. I've been able to edit the menu class of course, but not the li class. ALL I want to do is add some space between each link using margin. However the CSS is not working??

`CSS` I'm trying to use with class:

```
#block-system-main-menu li.menu__item is-leaf first leaf a{
    margin-bottom:15px;

}
```

ISN'T this right?

```
HTML

<div id="block-system-main-menu" class="block block-system contextual-links-region block-menu first last odd" role="navigation">
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf first leaf">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf leaf">
<li class="menu__item is-leaf last leaf">
<a class="menu__link active" title="" href="/">Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The margins on `a` are ignored unless it's displayed as block/inline-block.

If you have multiple classes, then you need to join them with `.` because otherwise css mistakes them for element names (as pointed out by Benjamin)

To make a larger area clickable, I'd suggest using padding instead of margins, but that depends on what you want.

```
#block-system-main-menu li.menu__item.is-leaf.leaf a
{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7SWB4/

Answer (score 0):

> li.menu__item is-leaf first leaf a

This assumes, that you have element `a` inside element `leaf` inside element `first` and etc. Class names should not contains spaces. Spaces separates different classes|elements.

So in your case you can just leave:

```
    #block-system-main-menu li.menu__item
```

And margin will apply to all list elements

Comment: Or use `#block-system-main-menu li.menu__item.is-leaf.leaf a` to apply the style only where the `li` has and a `menu__item` and `is-leaf` and `leaf` class